# Socket option IPV6_PKTINFO

Tags: sockets

I would like to use IPV6_PKTINFO option to specify an outgoing IPv6 address in sendmsg(). The socket is not bound neither to an address nor to an interface. Should I always specify ifindex together with source address

(according to rfc3542 :

The kernel must verify that the requested source address is indeed a
   unicast address assigned to the node.  When the address is a scoped
   one, there may be ambiguity about its scope zone.  This is
   particularly the case for link-local addresses.  In such a case, the
   kernel must first determine the appropriate scope zone based on the
   zone of the destination address or the outgoing interface (if known),
   then qualify the address.  This also means that it is not feasible to
   specify the source address for a non-binding socket by the
   IPV6_PKTINFO sticky option, unless the outgoing interface is also
   specified.  The application should simply use bind() for such
   purposes.
)

If I don't specify ifindex does it mean that this option should be ignored?
Thanks, Renata

Answer (score 0):

If you know the interface index, you could specify it.  It is not required unless you are attempting to set a an IPv6 Link Local address.